# Creating a triangle in css with a gradient background

Tags: css, css-shapes, psd

I am trying to create a triangle in css with a gradient background. I have not had any success as yet. Is there way to do this to bring off this effect seen in the image below.
(The triangle that is attached to the Wrong password error box.)

**Design in Photoshop**
[image]

**This is the design I have so far in HTML and CSS.**

[image]

Here is the css I have for the triangle at the moment.

```
.error-triangle {
    wwidth: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top:    10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right:  10px solid blue;
    margin-top: 64px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(102,65,65,.25), 2px 3px 5px rgba(70,34,34,.25), inset 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.25);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(102,65,65,.25), 2px 3px 5px rgba(70,34,34,.25), inset 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.25);
            box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(102,65,65,.25), 2px 3px 5px rgba(70,34,34,.25), inset 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.25);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #eb6767, #d94040 35%, #eb6767);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #eb6767, #d94040 35%, #eb6767);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #eb6767, #d94040 35%, #eb6767);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #eb6767, #d94040 35%, #eb6767);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(to top, #eb6767, #d94040 35%, #eb6767);
}
```

I was using this [tutorial on CSS tricks.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Comment: css only arrows: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Creating triangles (or other shapes - [pentagons, hexagons](http://dabblet.com/gist/3805071), octagons, [decagons](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/lDLwG), [dodecagons](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/pAlJg), [tetradecagons](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/fzFcu), [octadecagons](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/LuIJx) and so on) with a gradient (or any other kind of image background) is really easy with CSS transforms.

But in this case you don't even need a triangle. You just need to rotate a square pseudo-element by 45deg and apply the gradient on that from corner to corner.

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/Ajscx)

```
<div class='warn'></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.warn {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 1px darkred;
  width: 12em; height: 3em;
  border-radius: .2em;
  background: linear-gradient(lightcoral, firebrick);
}
.warn:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 0;
  margin: -.35em -.45em;
  border-left: inherit; border-bottom: inherit;
  /* pick width & height such that 
     the diagonal of the square is 1em = 1/3 the height of the warn bubble */
  width: .7em; height: .7em;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .2em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, firebrick -100%, lightcoral 200%);
  content: '';
}
```

Comment: this looks awesome. can you also add text shadow to the code ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSS triangle, but not a CSS triangle that is itself a gradient. The only trick I would suggest is to pick a color that most resembles the color within the gradient background. It just depends on how big your gradient actually is, and how well the triangle will blend in.

For the red div, you could try using the color #d94040, but then it will lack a border and a drop shadow. However, these can be added. To add a border to a CSS triangle, you can place a  inside your  that is also a CSS triangle that is the same size. TThis would require using absolute positioning and z-index to overlap them.

Or you can use ::after or ::before to create your CSS triangles without the added HTML code, but then that would only work in modern browsers only.

Comment: Ok. So do you think it would be best if I just use an image of the triangle instead?

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't use a gradient at all. That would make it look less like a button, and more like a warning.

Comment: Actually, you can create a triangle with a gradient background very easily by using transforms. http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/cBmxv

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3, you can create a triangle with the 'border trick'. This border can be colored and can have a background.

WebKit now (and Chrome 12 at least) supports gradients as border image.

For a more supported solution i suggest you to 'gradient' the background of a :before pseudo element for witch you would apply a 'background-gradient' + the ( css triangle with border ) trick.

[Here is a cssTriangle generator](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) for you to experiment.