# Create responsive triangle with text

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, css-shapes

I need to created a responsive triangle using css and html. The triangle will comprise of text and as the text would increase I want the size of triangle to also increase.

Below is the fiddle which I have created.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardikj/EZ8wA/10/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top-layer-content banner-notch"></div>
    <a class="icon-play fa fa-play-circle-o" rel="lightbox" href="#">
        <p> See it in action</p>
    </a>
<div>
```

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
.banner-notch {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 220px solid #000;
    border-left: 220px solid transparent;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.6;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}

.wrapper a{
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;
    right:20px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:25px;
    background-position:0 50px;
}

.wrapper .fa-play-circle-o:before{
    padding-left:38px;
}

.wrapper p{
    font-size:16px;
}
```

I checked the follow links but it seems the triangle shape is different and the text does not seem to wrap. Text starts overflowing.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112819/css-triangle-containing-text) and [link2](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/TRuQc/)

Thanks,
Hardik

Comment: why don't you use a background-image? we can't expect everything to be done in CSS..

Comment: I agree...previously we had achieved the same using an image, but now we are told to achieve the same using CSS... :( I was wondering if there is a possibility of achieving the same via CSS-CSS3..Thanks for your valuable time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pseudo elements and `transform:rotate()` to make a triangle that adapts to the size of its content.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/rP36H/)**

[image: triangle that adpats to its content]

This technique might need a bit of tweaking according to the context you use it in (container with to traingle width ratio) and the design you want when text becomes larger.

*HTML:*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="icon-play fa fa-play-circle-o" rel="lightbox" href="#">
        <p> See it in action</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    padding:0 1% 0 30%;
    margin-right:5%;
}
.fa-play-circle-o{
    display:block;
    margin:130% 0 2%;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
}
.fa-play-circle-o:before{
    font-size:30px;
}

.wrapper:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#666666;
    width:500%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;right:0;
    z-index:-1;

    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

    -ms-transform-origin:100% 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    transform-origin:100% 0;    
}
```

Comment: Clever!! Awesome way to implement, didn't think of rotating the div at all. Thanks for the fiddle and the response!!

Also thanks to @Mr_Green for the idea and time..

Comment: @Hardik glad I could help, don't hesitate to vote up both answers if they helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible using just CSS Gradient. As I am not good with gradients, I used [online CSS gradient generator](http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients/)  and did the following:

**CSS**

```
.triangle {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left top, color-stop(0, #000000), color-stop(0.5, #FFFFFF));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left top, #000000 0%, #FFFFFF 50%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #000000 0%, #FFFFFF 50%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #000000 0%, #FFFFFF 50%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left top, #000000 0%, #FFFFFF 50%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #000000 0%, #FFFFFF 50%);
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dN5Z/2/)**

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15439024/1577396)